# Change the background color of UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I'd like to change the background color of an UINvaigationBar and I used tintColor property but it's not changing the color. You can checkout the code below.

In my Appdelegate I create a UITabBarController

```
tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

Then I create a UINavigationController and attach my UITableViewController to it

```
UINavigationController *myNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
```

Then attached the UINavigationControllers to my tabbar like this

```
[tabbar setViewControllers:viewControllers]; //viewControllers is an array of UINavigationControllers
```

I tried setting the property tintColor in myAppdelegate like this

```
[[myNavigation navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

But this didn't work as expected and so I tried the same in my ViewController

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Test";
    }
```

And still nothing happens. Please checkout the image below to see how navigation bar looks now.

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Cheers
Jugs

Comment: Well this sounds strange.. For me [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; this line works cool..

Comment: Upvoted your Question so someone will notice it.. :-))

Comment: yeah..strange and weird! I tried setting the titleView  self.navigationItem.titleView = viewForTitle; and that works. So I'm referencing the correct UINvaigationController object I guess.

Comment: @Aadhira - yes will do if that helps in fixing my NavigationBar tintColor issue ;)

Comment: @Jugs, Hey even I have tested your code. Everything works fine. Pl.see the [attachment](http://cl.ly/1p3H1z0M3I3S1w2m061B)

Comment: Thanks! What version of SDK are you compiling this against ? Doubt this is a version issue which might have been resolved in the recent updates. FYI - I'm compiling with SDK 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around you may can use image on place of tint color please check below code for same.

```
if ([myNavigation respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:)]) {
        [myNavigation setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BAR_IMAGE_NAME] forbarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }else {
        [myNavigation insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BAR_IMAGE_NAME]] autorelease]  atIndex:0];
    }
```